# Google Earth Engine band did not match any bands error

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I am trying to composite S2 images by different technique but the composites for the 25 and 33 percentiles  (ee.Reducer.percentile([XX])) its giving an error :

```
p33: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'B2' did not match any bands.
p25: Layer error: Image.select: Pattern 'B2' did not match any bands.
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
//Se define la variable del CPC determinado y extent
var fires = table
//********************************************************************************************************//
//Extensión del raster en que se desea descargar los indices (metros a partir del CPC)
var extent_raster = 10000 ;
var b5km_fires = fires.geometry().buffer(extent_raster); 
    b5km_fires = b5km_fires.bounds();

//1.- Indicar Zona UTM a la que corresponde el CPC
var Zona_utm = '13'; // ---> INDICAR ZONA UTM EN DOS DIGITOS (p.e. 11,12,13,14,15,16)
//2.- Fechas de inicio y término en AAAA-MM-DD (AAAA = 4 digitos año, MM = 2 para el mes y DD = 2 para el dia)
var FECHA_INICIO =  ee.Date(fires.aggregate_first('FECHA_INI'));// ---> INDICAR FECHA DE **INICIO** DEL INCENDIO
var FECHA_TERMINO = ee.Date(fires.aggregate_first('FECHA_TER')); // ---> INDICAR FECHA DE **TERMINO** DEL INCENDIO
//3.- Se define el periodo de análisis entre pre y post
var dw = 30; // ---> INDICAR NÚMERO DE DÍAS del COMPUESTO PRE Y POST (30,60,90)
//4.- Indicar el nombre de la carpeta donde se van a guardar los raster (se debe crear primero en su drive) (L204)
var carpeta = 'incendios';

  //Fecha del periodo PRE a partir del atributo "FECHA_INI" en el CPC
var prefire_end = ee.Date(FECHA_INICIO); 
var prefire_start = prefire_end.advance(-dw,'day');
  //Fecha del periodo POST a partir del atributo "FECHA_TER" en el CPC
var postfire_start = ee.Date(FECHA_TERMINO);
var postfire_end =  postfire_start.advance(dw,'day');
  //Nombre del incendio
  print(ee.String('Incendio: ').cat(ee.String(fires.aggregate_first("ID_CPC"))));
  print(ee.String('Zona UTM seleccionada: ').cat(ee.String(Zona_utm)));
  //Fechas en que ocurrio el incendio y días de los periodos pre y post
  print(ee.String('Ocurrió entre: ').cat(prefire_end.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)).cat(' y ').cat(postfire_start.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)));
  print(ee.String('Ventana de días (pre y post): ').cat(ee.Number(dw)).cat(' días'));
  print(ee.String('Periodo pre: ').cat(prefire_start.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)).cat(' a ').cat(prefire_end.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)));
  print(ee.String('Periodo post: ').cat(postfire_start.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)).cat(' a ').cat(postfire_end.format('YYYY-MM-dd', null)));
//========================================================================================================
//Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

var s2_clear_sky = function(image){
  // 1.Locate SCL product
  var B1Band = image.select('B1');
  var scl = image.select('SCL');
  // 2.Apply mask to the image
  // Select values: 
  var wantedPixels = scl.eq(4)        //Vegetation
                 .or(scl.eq(5))       //Not vegetated
                 .or(scl.eq(7))       //Unclassified    
                 .or(B1Band.lt(2000))
  ;
  return image.updateMask(wantedPixels)
   .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
};

// This is the Sentinel 2 collection (all the possible available Sentinel-2 imagery)
var S2SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
            .filterBounds(b5km_fires)
            .filterDate(prefire_start, postfire_end)
            .map(maskS2clouds);

var S2_collection = S2SR.map(s2_clear_sky);

// Bands that we want to be displayed
var S2_bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12'];

// This turns the whole S2 collection into one image, finding the middle value for each pixel
var S2pr_min = S2_collection.filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false)
          .min().select(S2_bands).clip(b5km_fires);
var S2pr_ave = S2_collection.filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false)
          .mean().select(S2_bands).clip(b5km_fires);
var S2pr_p33 = S2_collection.filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false).reduce(ee.Reducer
          .percentile([33])).select(S2_bands).clip(b5km_fires);
var S2pr_p25 = S2_collection.filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false).reduce(ee.Reducer
          .percentile([25])).select(S2_bands).clip(b5km_fires);


// This controls how we want the S2 image to be displayed
var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'],
};

Map.addLayer(S2pr_min, visualization,'min');
Map.addLayer(S2pr_ave, visualization,'ave', false);
Map.addLayer(S2pr_p33, visualization,'p33', false);
Map.addLayer(S2pr_p25, visualization,'p25', false);

//Establecer parametros de simbología para el CPC
var cpcVis = fires.style({
  color: '0000FF',
  width: 5,
  fillColor: '00000000',  // relleno transparente
  lineType: 'solid'
});

// This automatically pans the map to the middle of our area of interest
Map.centerObject(b5km_fires);
Map.addLayer(cpcVis, null, 'CPC'); //Agregar a "layers" en el visualizador el CPC (var "fires")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, include a link to your script in the code editor in future questions (using the `Get Link` button). Here, we're missing `table`, and that required some useless effort on my part to get this running.

The error message is pretty spot on - the problem is that you're selecting band names that doesn't exist. The percentile reducer appends `_p33` and `_p25` to your band names.

```
print(
  S2_collection
    .filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([33]))
    .bandNames()
)
```

Another improvement you could make is to combine the reducers and have the collection reduced in a single operation. Performance will be better. It could look something like this:

```
var reduced = S2_collection
  .filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end)
  .select(S2_bands)
  .reduce(
    ee.Reducer.min()
      .combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true)
      .combine(ee.Reducer.percentile([25, 33]), null, true)
  )

var S2pr_min = reduced.select('.*_min').rename(S2_bands)
var S2pr_ave = reduced.select('.*_mean').rename(S2_bands)
var S2pr_p33 = reduced.select('.*_p33').rename(S2_bands)
var S2pr_p25 = reduced.select('.*_p25').rename(S2_bands)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f4102a5d2ebeb1458a70fd73d8cb9b4

Comment: Here's the link code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/71ac5f6e3625a1ae46c689edf9dfef4d

Comment: It works perfectly, and it simplifies better the code, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

That is the error you get if `select` after a reducer.

After a reducer, the layers change the name. i.e. a mean reducer may turn `B8` to `B8_mean`.

So select before the reducer, and you will be good!

For example, in your code:

```
var S2pr_min = S2_collection.filterDate(prefire_start, prefire_end).sort('GENERATION_TIME', false)
          .min().select(S2_bands).clip(b5km_fires);
```

After `.min()` the `select(S2_bands)` will give you an error. Maybe define a new `S2_bands_min` and it should have `_min` after all the elements in `S2_bands`.

I hope it helps!